# Override function (with hook) in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I have this situation:

parent theme:

functions.php

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/theme-functions.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/theme-hooks.php");
```

theme-function.php

```
function name_of_this_function() {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
add_action ('hook','name_of_this_function');
```

theme-hooks.php

```
function hook() {
    do_action('hook');
}
```

How can I override that action in my child functions.php given that mine is called before? I tried:

```
remove_action ('hook','name_of_this_function');
```

but of course this return false

Answer (score 2):

I came to an answer after many attempts (miserably failed) and a lot of reading of documentation online.

The solution resides in the "after_setup_theme" hook.

Before I was adding my actions "on top" of the parent's, meaning that i had two headers, two footers and so on. Of course the problem was that my functions.php was not able to remove something that was not added yet.

This was caused by wordpress behavior that runs functions.php of the child before the one of the parent theme.

The solution to this problem is to add a function after the setup of theme with a priority that force it to runs after the one of the parent. In this way ALL functions of the parent would be initialized (the after setup of parent is called as last function) and I would be able to remove some actions.
This is the syntax:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_setup', 3);
function my_setup(){
    /* CUSTOM FOOTER */
    remove_action('footer_hook','parent_site_info',99);
    add_action('footer_hook','site_info',99);
}
```

That solved the problem.